# Wrong conversion of date difference to numeric In Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset:

```
     A                               B
2019-06-19 09:18:00         2019-06-22 09:14:37
2019-06-27 22:35:00         2019-06-27 22:04:20
2019-06-26 19:50:00         2019-06-26 21:18:45
```

where it represent the datetime for both column.

I wanted to construct a columns C that shows the difference in date time as hours in decimal and apply the following transformation.

```
raw_data['C']= raw_data['B'] - raw_data['A']
raw_data['C']= round(raw_data['C']/np.timedelta64(1,'h'),2)
```

and I managed to get the correct value calculation:

```
  C               A                         B
71.94    2019-06-22 09:14:37      2019-06-19 09:18:00
-0.51    2019-06-27 22:04:20      2019-06-27 22:35:00
1.48     2019-06-26 21:18:45      2019-06-26 19:50:00
```

However, when I tried to create a categorical variable D, where it will be 'Pass' if column C is smaller than 3, I have the wrong conversion for the third row. I.e. it should be 'Pass' value.

```
raw_data['D']= "Fail"
raw_data.loc[raw_data['C']<3, 'D']= 'Pass'


  D        C
71.94    Fail
-0.51    Pass
1.48     Fail
```

May I know what could be the possible reasons for the failed conversion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested and for me working correct.

Alternative solution with [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) and [`Series.round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html), last for new column is used [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
raw_data['C']= raw_data['B'] - raw_data['A']
raw_data['C']=  raw_data['C'].dt.total_seconds().div(3600).round(2)

raw_data['D']= np.where(raw_data['C']<3,'Pass',"Fail") 
print (raw_data)
                    A                   B      C     D
0 2019-06-19 09:18:00 2019-06-22 09:14:37  71.94  Fail
1 2019-06-27 22:35:00 2019-06-27 22:04:20  -0.51  Pass
2 2019-06-26 19:50:00 2019-06-26 21:18:45   1.48  Pass
```

Comment: I am thinking it is because of using the loc method, if I were to use:  raw_data['D']= "Fail"
raw_data.loc[raw_data['C']<3, 'D']= 'Pass', it will return the same error.

Comment: @user90831 - If using `raw_data['D']= np.where(raw_data['C']<3,'Pass',"Fail")` it working?